# How to calculate viewport width based on device specification

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

Im trying to understand how vieport width is calculated for mobile devices. I've tried it on real device and it works the same but I'll paste screenshot with emulator.

The question is: why the viewport width is 432px when the device width is 1080px and density is 420dpi? I undestand that the viewport metatag should set the viewport width to device actual width right? So it should be 1080px yes?

This might be trivial but i dont undestand from that 432px came from exactly.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: [This Resourse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) meight be helpful for you!

Comment: I've found out that device screen resolution is not the same as viewport resolution. And found some links to actual expected viewport sizes for vary devices: http://viewportsizes.com/. But i still dont know how it has been calculated in my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
ViewPortSize = ScreenPixelResolution / DevicePixelRatio
```

eg: iPhone XS Max

ScreenPixelResolution: 2688 x 1242

DevicePixelRatio: 3

ViewPortSize: 896 x 414

Comment: Where do you get `DevicePixelRatio`? I do not see it as part of device specification.

Comment: @greatvovan, to get a device pixel ratio, you will divide the resolution width size by viewport width size. Yes, you will never know the viewport width size to get the device pixel ratio to get the viewport size.